# When i update my ram from 8gb ram(4+4) to 16gb ram(4+4+4+4) my pc does showing no display

Tags: memory, asus

When I update my RAM from 8 GB RAM (4+4) to 16 GB RAM (4+4+4+4) my PC does showing no display.

I have GIGABYTE-asus -A320m gaming and ran with 2 RAM modules (2 x 4 GB). Now I have bought another two, but after pluging in the PC doesn't boot. It starts, run for a while and turn off and after few second it try to ran again.

I suppose that it could be because another two RAM slots are expansion and there is something to set up.

RAM are compatible, I have tried to run one of the older and one new in pair and system runs. Both new run too well. Problem is when I use slots DDR4.

Any suggestion or advice?

Comment: does the problem go away when you remove the new ram?

Comment: and does it work when you change the RAM slots?

Comment: Combining RAM can be hit or miss and sometimes they just wont work together whatever you do. Update your BIOS to the latest version for best compatibility and try different ways of putting the ram in (slowest RAM in A1 and B1 for example).